# Grunt background image on gruntfile.js in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Just downloaded the VS 2015 RC and have been playing around with Gruntfile.js. I noticed Mads Kristensen demo'ing this, and various JSON files would have a background image displayed in the lower right corner based on the library it was used for (Grunt, Bower, etc...)

It looked like:

[image]

Anyone know how to get those background images to display?

Answer (score 0):

It is called `Adornments`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#adornments)

> Adornments are graphic effects that are not directly related to the
>   font and color of the characters in the text view. For example, the
>   red squiggle underline that is used to mark non-compiling code in many
>   programming languages is an embedded adornment, and tooltips are
>   pop-up adornments. Adornments are derived from UIElement and implement
>   ITag. Two specialized types of adornment tag are the
>   SpaceNegotiatingAdornmentTag, for adornments that occupy the same
>   space as the text in a view, and the ErrorTag, for the squiggle
>   underline.

It's not a new feature from `VS2015`, it already existed in `VS2010`.

Several extensions allow you to put a custom image as a watermark on the text editor.

If you want to know how it is done under the hood, [here](https://github.com/nategreenwood/VSEditorBackgroundChangerExtension) is a GitHub repository of an extension.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885244.aspx) is another MSDN article that explains which classes to implement if you want to create your extension.